# How to prevent Eclipse formatter inserting blank lines in block comment before annotations

Tags: eclipse, formatting

I have:

```
/*
 * Search file
 *
 * @param folderPath - path to search.
 * @param resourceResolver - ResourceResolver.
 */
```

Eclipse format it to:

```
/*
 * Search file
 *
 * @param folderPath - path to search.
 *
 * @param resourceResolver - ResourceResolver.
 */
```

How can I prevent such adding new line before "@param resourceResolver"? Can it be a bug?

"Remove blank lines" feature the line after "Search file", so it's not convenient for me.

Disabling "Enable block comment formating" is also bad choise because of indention.

Comment: My Eclipse does not format as you mentioned.  Given what you said it seems like you already know this, but all the formatting settings are available in Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatters.  After playing with the settings there briefly, I'm not able to reproduce this.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: By the way, I reproduce it with 4.7.0 and 4.6.1 versions. Also just in case, I'll notice, it's not javaDoc.

Comment: An interesting problem which I cannot reproduce using version 4.7.3a. Are you using a default formatter, or one that you created? Go to **Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Active Profile** for the name. If you use a customized formatter try using one of the default formatters (**Java Conventions** or **Eclipse**) to see whether the problem with the unwanted blank line persists.